# Misunderstanding about electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

- Consider any point on the loop now if
- **How is the magnetic force acting on charge and won't charges present at  both opposite corners will experience same force in same direction then how is there current**
- **If charges are first taken at rest then how is this force acting and if we are taking motion of charge relative to the magnetic field then arent both charges and magnetic field moving antiparallel then won't magnetic force have zero effect on charges**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is arising from this equation:

$$\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$$

At first glance, it definitely does appear that if the free charges $q$ are at rest ($\mathbf{v} = 0 $) then there should be no force. You are correct that there is no force on these charges *caused* by the field alone. In your diagram, what is causing these particles to move is a time-varying *change* in the magnetic field, which works according to [Lenz's law](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law):

> An induced electromotive force (emf) always gives rise to a current whose magnetic field opposes the original change in magnetic flux.

This is consistent with Faraday's law of induction:

[image]

In the presence of a changing magnetic field, free charge will attempt to move in such a way to counter the change in the magnetic field.

In the loop that you have shown here, if there is an increasing magnetic field in the 'up' direction, the free charge in the conducting loop will try to do whatever it can in order to produce a magnetic field in the 'down' direction. For a current loop to have a magnetic field in the down direction, the right-hand rule tells us that positive charge must move in a clock-wise direction around the coil. This is consistent with the diagram you have provided.

Comment: i know that changing magnetic field produces electric field but that electric field is produced when there is potential difference for which you require force similar to motional emf case now can you tell me that if im wrong or that varying magnetic field is producing electric field because of someither reason thanks

Comment: You are precisely correct. A changing magnetic field produces an electric field, which we observe as an electro motive force (emf). This is shown in Faradays law, which is one of Maxwells four fundamental equations of electromagnetism.

Comment: can you send me a diagram that how these charges will seperate when this loop experiences varying magnetic field and how this force is acting or any related article because i cant still hold of the idea if we are moving the loop towards magnetic field then charges are moving parallel to magnetic field so magnetic force should be zero and no electric field should be created

Comment: No charges are moving parallel to the magnetic field. All charges are moving either clockwise (cw), or counterclockwise (ccw) to the field. These are orthogonal directions. The diagram you have provided is the best way to describe this. If you move the loop towards the magnetic field, you are correct to state then there will be no magnetic force (no emf) caused by this movement.